# Determining a nonlinear function passes through $2$ certain points

Tags: calculus, functions, algebraic-geometry

How to determine a function of that type below?

$$y=\frac 1x$$

**The point is**: it passes through $2$ certain points, let's say:

$(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$

For example: $(0,30)$, $(0.2,4)$

And it may have some constants or whatever.

Let's say $y=\cfrac{a}{bx+c}-d$

Thanks.

Comment: My example stands for the points, not equation. Thanks for feedback about trigonometry. I removed it.

Comment: Your example looks like a scaled and translated version of the first function. Do you mean to find parameters such that the resulting function will include your points?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac a {bx+c} -d$.
You are interested in values for the parameters $a,b,c,d$, such that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$ are satisfied. In general, there are infinitely many solutions, because there are only two equations determinating four parameters.

A more specific form for $f$ which allows only finitely many solutions would be $f(x) = \frac 1 {x-a}+b$, which describes a translated hyperbola.
Again, $a,b$ are given by the solutions of the system of equations $f(x_1)\frac 1 {x_1 -a}+b=y_1$ and $f(x_2)\frac 1 {x_2 -a}+b=y_2$.
This leads to solving a quadratic equation with the four parameters $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ and is quite tedious. According to Mathematica, the solution to

> FullSimplify[
>    Solve[{Subscript[y, 1] == b + (-a + Subscript[x, 1])^(-1), 
>      Subscript[y, 2] == b + (-a + Subscript[x, 2])^(-1)}, {a, b}, 
>     MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]]

is 
$$\left\{\left\{a\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(y_1-y_2\right)
   \left(\left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(y_1-y_2\right)-4\right)}}{y_1-y_2}+x_1+x_2\right), 
\\b\to
   \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(y_1-y_2\right)
   \left(\left(x_1-x_2\right)
   \left(y_1-y_2\right)-4\right)}}{x_1-x_2}+y_1+y_2\right)\right\},
\left\{a\to \frac{1}{2}
   \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(y_1-y_2\right) \left(\left(x_1-x_2\right)
   \left(y_1-y_2\right)-4\right)}}{y_1-y_2}+x_1+x_2\right),
\\b\to \frac{1}{2}
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(y_1-y_2\right) \left(\left(x_1-x_2\right)
   \left(y_1-y_2\right)-4\right)}}{x_1-x_2}+y_1+y_2\right)\right\}\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite and simplify, replace any constants with easier constants so you get a polynomial:

$$\sum_{(k,l)\in {\mathbb N}^2}c_{kl} \cdot x^ky^l = 0$$

Now given you have prescribed points to be true then $x^ky^l$ will be constant and you have a linear equation system to solve in terms of $c_{kl}$. What remains is the book-keeping of ordering $c_{kl}$ into a vector and solving for it.

---

You may need to apply regularization as there could be many polynomial curves passing through your points. Adding a diagonal matrix to the left hand side of the resulting equation system: $\lambda {\bf D}$ where $\bf D$ grows rather fast as some function of $k$ and $l$ in the corresponding positions.

---

**EDIT** to avoid the linear equation system being homogeneous finding the minimum norm solution 0 vector we can prescribe a non-zero **level set**:

For example any expression encouraging $c_{00}=-1$ for all points to be included should force us away from unwanted trivial zero-vector solutions.